# Challenge (+) Problem 32, Chapter 1 (Pigeonhole Principle), A Walk Through Combinatorics, Miklos Bona

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

**Question**:
Let T be a triangle with angles of 30, 60, and 90, and a hypotenuse of 1.
We choose ten points inside T at random. Prove that there will be four points among them that can be covered by a half-circle of radius 0.42.

Comment: As argued in the answer, I feel the step 4 very strange. What you actually need to claim is that 3 semicircles covers your right triangle, and given that the radius is 0.42 (the diameter almost covered the $\sqrt3/2$ side), it should be fairly easy to do so.

Comment: Hey. I appreciate your input, @HwChu (as well as Y. Forman's). I think I can fix the reasoning in 4) by showing that even the (smaller) half circle covers the smaller rectangle (a third of the rectangle). I believe this fixes the problem, because we can divide Triangle T into three (unequal) components, each of which corresponds to a smaller rectangle (that is, each of the smaller rectangles will contain a portion of Triangle T). By PHP, one of these three components must have 4 points, and a semi circle covers fully the component.

Comment: I see this as exactly doing what you proposed, as one semi-circle can cover each of the three small rectangles, and, since each rectangle covers a unique portion of the triangle T, three semi-circles covers the triangle.

Comment: Yes. A semicircle can cover the one-third rectangle, so it should work. Actually I believe this is a loose bound. After some graphing I believe that it is still true if the radius shrinks to about 0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My proof**:

**1)** I took the rectangle composed of *two* such triangles (Area = **0.433**).

**2)** By the pigeonhole principle, if I divide the rectangle into *three* equal areas (Area = **0.144**), one among the *three* must hold *four* of *ten* points placed within the larger, undivided rectangle.

**3)** Because the radius of the half circle (**r = 0.42**) is larger than **1/2** of both sides of the smaller rectangle (**0.42** > **0.25**, **0.42** > **0.288675**), and larger than **1/2** of its diagonal (**0.42** > **0.288675**), placing a half circle of **r = 0.42** whose diameter is aligned with the side of length **1/2** and center is placed at its midpoint will encompass the whole of the smaller rectangle and cover a larger area.

4) Because we can divide Triangle T into three (unequal) portions, each of which corresponds to one of the three smaller rectangles (for each of the smaller rectangles will contain one of the three portions of Triangle T), and because, by the PHP, one of these three components must have 4 points, a half-circle of **r = 0.42** contains the portion with 4 points fully. Therefore, any *four* of *ten* points placed in triangle T can be covered by a semi-circle of **r = 0.42**.

---

**Information for you that you may find useful**:

**A)** Area of half-circle with radius 0.42 = **0.277088**

**B)** Area of triangle = **0.2165**

**C)** Area of rectangle = **0.433**

**D)** Area of a third of rectangle = **0.144** (with sides **1/2** and **radical(3)/6**, that is, a third of radical(3)/2)

**E)** Lengths of sides of smaller rectangle are **1/2** and **radical(3)/6** or **0.288675**

**F)** Length of diagonal of smaller rectangle is **1/radical(3)** or **0.57735**

**G)** Length of half this diagonal = **1/[2*radical(3)]** or **0.288675**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced by point #4. Suppose the ten points placed originally happened to be in triangle T, and so did the circle. Then how do I know if cutting the circle in half won't cut out some of the points?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Y. Forman.